# Como contabilizar cuantas veces se dio click a una opción en un test

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

tengo problemas para resolver este ejercicio que es un test. Lo que quiero hacer es que contabilice cuantas veces se marco la letra a,b,c,d de todas las pregunta  y que se muestre en un gráfico, me recomendaron usar chart.js para el gráfico. Se los agradecería si me ayudan, soy nuevo en la carrera. Que tengan buen día.

```
html:



<div class="container">
    <h2>Encuesta</h2>
        <h4>1. ¿Cómo se ve tu piel en este momento?</h4>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio"> Lisa y con brillo natural, no oleoso
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio"> Algo opaca y seca
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio"> Me brilla toda la cara
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio"> Algunas zonas están brillosa y otras
                seca
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h4>2. ¿Cómo son tus poros?</h4>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio"> Finos y poco visible
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio"> Casi imperceptibles
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio"> Son grandes y visibles en todas partes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio"> Son grandes en mentón, nariz y/o frente
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Qué has intentado? Tal vez [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874) te pueda ayudar a obtener una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver tu problema puedes hacer lo siguiente. Etiquetar cada uno de los inputs radio con una clase correspondiente a su valor a, b, c o d. Luego agregar un botón contar, que al hacer click, ejecute una función que cuente cuantas de las diferentes clases están seleccionadas. Esta función podría ser algo así:

```
function contarRespuestas() {
  //Inicias la grafica con todos los valores en cero
  for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data[index] = 0;}

  // Cuentas cuantas veces está marcada cada opcion y lo seteas en el grafico
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].forEach((option,i) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(`.${option}`).forEach(checkbox => {
    if(checkbox.checked){
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] += 1
    }
  })
  myChart.update()
})
}
```

Esta simplemente va a seleccionar todas las clases a y va a contar cuantas están seleccionadas, todas las clases b y contará las seleccionadas, y así sucesivamente. Estos valores los actualizará en el gráfico de chart.js y se mostrarán en pantalla.

Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        datasets: [{
            label:'Respuestas',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }
});

function contarRespuestas() {
  for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
myChart.data.datasets[0].data[index] = 0;
  }
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].forEach((option,i) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(`.${option}`).forEach(checkbox => {
if(checkbox.checked){
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] += 1
}
  })
  myChart.update()
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.5.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Encuesta</h2>
        <h4>1. ¿Cómo se ve tu piel en este momento?</h4>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input a" name="optradio1"> Lisa y con brillo natural, no oleoso
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id='radio1' type="radio" class="form-check-input b" name="optradio1"> Algo opaca y seca
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id='radio2' type="radio" class="form-check-input c" name="optradio1"> Me brilla toda la cara
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id='radio3' type="radio" class="form-check-input d" name="optradio1"> Algunas zonas están brillosa y otras
                seca
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h4>2. ¿Cómo son tus poros?</h4>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id='radio4' type="radio" class="form-check-input a" name="optradio2"> Finos y poco visible
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id='radio5' type="radio" class="form-check-input b" name="optradio2"> Casi imperceptibles
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id='radio6' type="radio" class="form-check-input c" name="optradio2"> Son grandes y visibles en todas partes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id='radio7' type="radio" class="form-check-input d" name="optradio2"> Son grandes en mentón, nariz y/o frente
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
  <div style="width: 100%; max-width: 500px; margin:auto">
  <button onclick="contarRespuestas()">Contar</button>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
 </div>
```